# React / Redux - async action is working without using thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, thunk

I recently tried something in my project and I was quite surprised that it worked. What I did was this :-

```
let result = {};
Axios.post("/auth", newUser).then(res => {
  // console.log(res);
  result = res.data;
  this.props.signupUser(result);
});
```

The above code was written inside onSubmit event handler of a form in react. I wanted to get the response from the POST request and store the response in redux store and I tried the above code and it worked. The result was stored in redux store. So my question is  was this supposed to work? and if yes then what's the purpose of redux thunk?

`signupUser` is a simple action creator, a function which returns a plain object and the variable `newUser` is an object which contains the form data.

Comment: You make your asynchron and after you call redux... With thunk you can call redux and inside the reducer make things asynchrone

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of thunk is to give you more control over the async actions. While your code works, consider some more advanced requirements:

- A different React component is supposed to show a loading animation while the request is in progress
- You you want to track all api error responses somewhere
- after the user has signed up, you want to trigger other requests for unrelated resources

Thunk facilitates all of those things in a more convenient way. You can also look at the current redux state at any point with `getState` in thunk actions. In general, it's better to separate concerns: React components show a signup form and are wired up with redux actions. The actions take care of api requests and data handling. Nothing is stopping you from writing all that code inside of a React component, but in a larger app this will get out of hand quickly.